# Table View Controller Problems

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uitableview

I added a table view into a view in interface builder and now I need to wire it up to some pre-made classes that you can generate in xcode. I set the tableview controller's class to the class in xcode and wired the dataSource and delegate to my table view but the app just crashes. Im not sure how to get data to properly load into my table view when using a tableview in a different view. If anyone knows how to do this any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have UITableView outlet, and connect from the File's Owner to the table in the IB.

Take a look at [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/03/recreating-uitableviewcontroller-to.html) too.